# Subset spatRaster layers; return layers that match subset names, ignore those that do not?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I'm looping through rasters and would like to select a subset of layers if they match certain layer names that I'm looking for. When using terra::subset, an error will occur if a layer name is specified that does not exist in the raster. Is there a way to just return layer names that match and ignore those that do not?

This throws an error but I'd like it to just return layer "A"

```
library(terra)
r1 <- rast(matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10))
r2 <- rast(matrix(200:101, nrow=10, ncol=10))
r3 <- rast(matrix(c(2,200), nrow=10, ncol=10))
s <- c(r1,r2,r3)
names(s) <- c("A","B","C")
print(s)
s2<-subset(s,c("A","D"))
```

> Error: [subset] invalid name(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this small variation:

```
ind <- match(c("A","D"), names(s))
ind <- ind[!is.na(ind)]

s[[ names(s)[ind] ]] # OR
terra::subset(s, names(s)[ind])
```

Following your example:

```
library(terra)
r1 <- rast(matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10))
r2 <- rast(matrix(200:101, nrow=10, ncol=10))
r3 <- rast(matrix(c(2,200), nrow=10, ncol=10))
s <- c(r1,r2,r3)
names(s) <- c("A","B","C")
print(s)


ind <- match(c("A","D"), names(s))
ind <- ind[!is.na(ind)]

> s[[ names(s)[ind] ]]
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 10, 0, 10  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. :  
source(s)   : memory
name        :   A 
min value   :   1 
max value   : 100
```

Comment: Thanks! To best follow my example perhaps change to ind <- match(c("A","D"), names(s))

Comment: An alternative:  `nms <- c("A", "D"); subset(s, nms[nms %in% names(s)])`